# Create New Instances of Object Within For Loop

Tags: object, for-loop

I am creating a program that prompts for lastname, age, and weight. It then displays that info, then asks again. Typing "finished" will make it stop asking and it will display all of the information for each person.

The class "Person" has lastName as String, age and weight as double.

I am stuck on how to create new instances of a person in the for loop and then print out each of those instances once the loop is done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String decision;
    Person Guy = null;

    for (int i =0; i<20; i++){
    Guy = new Person();
        System.out.println("Please enter a last name");    
        Guy.lastName = userInput.next();
            if (Guy.lastName.equalsIgnoreCase("finished")){
        break;
        }
    System.out.println("Please enter an age");
        Guy.age = userInput.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter a weight");
        Guy.weight = userInput.nextDouble();
    Guy.WriteOutput();     
    }

    for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
        Guy.WriteOutput();
        if (Guy == null){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're dropping the old guy on the floor with every iteration. Instead you want to add each guy to a structure (e.g. an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), and after the input phase is done then iterate over that list and print out each guy.